# Menu , Workspace and Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, caliburn.micro

I'm developing a new WPF application that will make large use of Caliburn Micro(2.x), Telerik WPF suite. I've created in starting from another WPF project that uses the 2 previous components (it uses CM 1.5.2) but I want to make thing rights and avoid the workaround done in past

In both application I've used the Telerik Conventions developed by [Valeriu Caraulean](https://github.com/vcaraulean/Caliburn.Micro.Telerik)

The main idea is to have a toplevel menu with a RadDocking for docking the items

Here's the WorkSpaceViewModel

```
public class WorkSpaceViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive, IHandle<MenuMessage>
{
    #region Variables
    private readonly IDockManager dockManager;
    private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public MenuViewModel Menu { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public WorkSpaceViewModel(MenuViewModel menu, IDockManager dockManager, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this.dockManager = dockManager;
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);

        Menu = menu;
    }

    protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
    {
        base.OnViewLoaded(view);

        dockManager.Link(this);

        Menu.GenerateMenu();
    }
```

And here's the WorkSpaceView

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="rowMenu" Height="Auto" MinHeight="30"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="rowDocking" Height="*"/>
        <!-- Height="Auto" -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#FFF1F5FB">
        <!-- Background="#FFF0F0F0"-->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>-->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <!--<ContentControl x:Name="Menu" cal:Bind.Model="{Binding Menu}"></ContentControl>-->
            <local:MenuView x:Name="Menu" cal:Bind.Model="{Binding Menu}" ></local:MenuView>
            <!--cal:Bind.Model="{Binding Menu}"-->
        </StackPanel>
        <Border BorderThickness="0.5" CornerRadius="7"  cal:Action.Target="{Binding}" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Background="#FFEFF7FC" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" MaxWidth="200">
            <telerik:RadExpander IsExpanded="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" telerik:AnimationManager.IsAnimationEnabled="True" ExpandDirection="Left">
                <telerik:RadExpander.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="LoggedUser" Background="Transparent" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="11" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <!--<telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Opzioni" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action OpenOptions($eventArgs)]"/>-->
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <!--<Image cal:Message.Attach="[Event PreviewMouseDown] = [Action ShowInfo()]"  cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding}" 
                               Width="14" Height="14">
                            <Image.Source>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="/DOME;component/Media/info.png"></BitmapImage>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>-->
                    </StackPanel>
                </telerik:RadExpander.Content>
            </telerik:RadExpander>
        </Border>
    </Grid>

    <telerik:RadDocking Grid.Row="1" Background="{Binding WorkspaceBackground}" x:Name="docking"   cal:Message.Attach="[Event ElementLoading] = [Action DockingLoading($eventArgs)]"   >
        <telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost >
            <telerik:RadSplitContainer ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleRadPaneGroups}" telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="splitContainer" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
        </telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
    </telerik:RadDocking>
</Grid>
```

Here's the MenuViewModel

```
public class MenuViewModel : Screen
{
    #region Variables
    private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    private List<VisualMenuItem> items;
    public List<VisualMenuItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
        }
    }

    public void GenerateMenu()
    {
        var menu = new List<VisualMenuItem>();

        menu.Add(new VisualMenuItem { Text = "Calendario", Tag = "calendario" });

        Items = menu;
    }
```

and the MenuView

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanConverter" />
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding}"
             Visibility="{Binding IsVisible,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource booleanConverter}}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="30"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <telerik:RadMenu  x:Name="MenuList" ClickToOpen="False"  BorderBrush="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Menu.Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"   
                 cal:Message.Attach="[Event ItemClick] = [Action OpenView($eventArgs)]" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  >
        <telerik:RadMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="telerik:RadMenuItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSeparator" Value="{Binding IsSeparator}" />
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="{Binding IsCheckable}" />
                <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnClick" Value="{Binding IsCheckable}" />

                <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="[Event SubmenuOpened] = [Action SubMenuOpen($source)]" />
            </Style>
        </telerik:RadMenu.ItemContainerStyle>

    </telerik:RadMenu>
</Grid>
```

The VisualMenuItem is defined as

```
 public class VisualMenuItem : ObservableCollection<VisualMenuItem>
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> MenuParameter { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public string ViewModelName { get; set; }
    public Type ViewModelType { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public bool StaysOpenOnClick { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
}
```

When the application loads there's no menu... in the previous version in the WorkSpaceView I was doing

```
  <local:MenuView x:Name="Menu" cal:Bind.Model="{Binding Menu}" ></local:MenuView>
```

But I've read that is not reccomended to use cal:Bind.Model="xxx" in 2.0 and also I would avoid putting a view in there, I would prefer to put ContentControl x:Name="Menu"

The other thing I wish to do is to load the menu after a login so the menuitems are filtered upon the authorization... in the old project I hide the not-allowed items but it's not so good

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`<ContentControl x:Name="Menu" />` should work just fine with what you have for code.  You are already injecting the MenuViewModel as it is...  But I would put a notification call on it when you do the instantiation.  cal:Bind.Model isn't necessary since the contentcontrol will take on the MenuView with the menuviewmodel you are injecting... ALso that is like taking ViewFirst and bastardizing ViewModelFirst all at the same time.

`public MenuViewModel Menu {
      get{ return menu ;}
      set{ 
            menu = value;
            NotifyOnPropertyChange();
         }
    }`